# calling a function to change int to binary

Tags: c++, function, binary

I've a function that converts int to binary, when calling it from the `main` function, it gives an error `binary: identifier not found` what's wrong in the code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int dec;
cin >> dec; 
binary(dec);
return 0;
}

void binary(int decimal) {
int remainder;

if(decimal <= 1) {
   std::cout << decimal;
   return;
}
remainder = decimal % 2;
binary(decimal >> 1);    
std::cout << remainder;
}
```

Comment: The compiler goes top-down.

Comment: This should be very early in your C++ book. You should either put the function above main, or write a function prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either move binary function implementation above main or have a prototype defined

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `binary` before you can use it. Either write your code to put function definitions above the functions that call them (not always possible, in case of recursion), or provide forward function declarations ... e.g., put

```
void binary(int decimal);
```

above your main function.

In large C++ projects, every source file has an accompanying header file that declares all the classes and functions defined by the source file. Then you just #include the header file into any source file that uses those classes and functions.

Comment: Note that in C++ declaration does not mean implementation - you can write `void binary(int decimal);` and all this tells the compiler is that the function exists and will be implemented (given a function body for) later.

Comment: @Patashu The OP provided the implementation of `binary`. I would be surprised if anyone thought that a mere declaration somehow magically provides the implementation.

Comment: What I mean is, you can't implement a function twice - and to the uninitiated, declaring a function might look like you're implementing it to do nothing.

Comment: @Patashu I think "declare binary before you can use it" covered that. Certainly there are people who pay no attention to what is written and make no attempt to understand terms like "declare", "definitions", "forward function declarations", and so on, but no further amount of explanation can be counted on to help.